# How to map elements into two table columns, two elements per row?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to get the end result to look like, (following [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_two_columns) example):

```
<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 300px;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
</style>

<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <Component />
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <Component />
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that I can't quite figure out how to do this in React. The original map function currently looks like:

```
<div className="main">
  {
    arrayOfComponents.map((({ name }), index) => (
      <Component
        key={`${index}-${name}`}
        label={name}
      />
    ))
  }
</div>
```

I've tried doing something like,

```
<div className="main">
  {
    arrayOfComponents.map((({ name }), index) => (
      <div className={index % 2 === 0 ? 'row' : ''}>
        <div className="column">
          <Component
            key={`${index}-${name}`}
            label={name}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    ))
  }
</div>
```

But that didn't seem to work, and if it did, it seems messy. How can I go about this?

`arrayOfComponents` looks something like

```
const arrayOfComponents = [
  { name: 'abc', key: 'value1'},
  { name: 'def', key: 'value2' },
  . . .
]
```

Comment: How does `arrayOfComponents`look like?

Comment: Updated OP, it's just a regular array of objects.

Comment: And you want them to be placed in col1 and 2 in alternating order?

Comment: Yep, that's it.

Comment: If there are more than two `column`s in a `row` they will automatically wrap as they have a `width: 50%` defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to map over the array and return the Component wrapped in a `div` with `className` of ***column*** like this :

```
<div className="main">
  <div className="row">
   {
    arrayOfComponents.map(({name},index) => (
        <div className="column">
          <Component
            key={`${index}-${name}`}
            label={name}
          />
        </div>
    ))
   }
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Create two equal columns that floats next to each other */
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.bg{
  background:orange;
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin: 0 auto 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row bg">
  <div class="column">
    <h2>Column 1</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <h2>Column 2</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="bg">
  <div class="column">
    <h2>Column 1</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <h2>Column 2</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: But this renders only one div element with the class `row`. What if I have 100 elements in  `arrayOfComponents` and I need 50 div's with the class `row` (because there are 2 `<Component />` elements per row)?

Comment: @MikeK You don't need multiple rows. One is fine. The columns will align automatically. Try increading the objects in the array.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Can you explain in one or two words why I don't need multiple rows, please?

Comment: @MikeK So that's basically css floats. So you need to have a container element which clears the float of the class `column`...here that container is the `row` . Only one is needed.`float` breaks the normal flow of the document and you have to clear it to make the flow normal again. See the example I made. The `bg` class has a border and a background. The div with `row` class expands till the columns but the one with no `row` class breaks. 

Read about floats here : https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

Answer (score 0):

If you specifically need additional `row` elements, You can use conditional rendering like this. This would create a new `row` after 2 `columns`.

```
<div className="main">
  {
    arrayOfComponents.map(({ name }, index) => index%2!=0?null:(
      <div className="row">
        <div className="column">
          <Component
            key={`${index}-${name}`}
            label={name}
          />
        </div>
        {arrayOfComponents[index+1] && (
        <div className="column">
          <Component
            key={`${index+1}-${arrayOfComponents[index+1].name}`}
            label={arrayOfComponents[index+1].name}
          />
        </div>
        )}
      </div>
    ))
  }
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use reduce for splitting your data:

```
const rows = arrayOfComponents.reduce((acc, rec, index) => {
    if (index % 2 === 0) {
      return [...acc, [rec]]
    }
    acc[acc.length - 1] = [...acc[acc.length - 1], rec]
    return acc
  }, [])


const Component = (props) => {
  return <div>
    <h2>{props.item.name}</h2>
    <p>{props.item.key}</p>
  </div>
}

const TodoApp = () => {
  return rows.map((row, index)=>{
    return <div key={index}>{
      row.map((col) => <div className="column" key={col.name}><Component item={col}/></div>)
    }</div>
  })
}
```

See full example in playground: https://jsfiddle.net/denisstukalov/ut8x9Lkq/21/#&togetherjs=Q7jLIOHHOP